# How do I tap into a power supply's standby wire?

Tags: arduino, power-supply

So I'm working on an Arduino project, I'm going to make a circuit board that's going to be inside my computer. The circuit needs to always have power, after a bit of googling, I found out that the standby (purple) wire seems to be perfect for what I want. I took an old computer and did this.

[image: Tapped into the standby wire, and a random ground wire]

[image: My project in its current state]

The LEDs barely glow, so it seems I don't draw enough power from the power supply. So I'm wondering, if it's because of the way I tapped into it? or if it simply doesn't provide enough current?

Comment: What voltage do you require? What voltage did you get?

Comment: Please draw a normal schematics of how do you connect things, with connector designation etc.

Comment: You can use the front panel usb connectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you are either connected to the wrong spot in the wiring harness or (much more likely) are using the Arduino Vin pin instead of powering it from the 5 V pin.

The +5VSB supply should at minimum be capable of delivering 2 amps. 
Look at the [ATX spec](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/ATX12V%20PSDG2.01.pdf) 3.3.3, and most modern ATX power supplies exceed this and can deliver 3-4 amps.

The Arduino needs a minimum of 6 V to power it from the Vin pin, so you can't use that. You need to be connected to the 5 V regulated line or to the USB connector XUSB line and leave Vin unconnected.
The Arduino will never have a current flow over 500 mA (that's the XUSB fuse rating. Please refer to the [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf).

I'd suggest that the best way for you to connect the Arduino to your ATX +5SB is to hack a USB cable and use the USB connector on the Arduino. That gives you a fused supply line with a removable connector ...much better than cutting into the ATX cabling the way you have.

Comment: You where right, I was using the Vin pin. I changed it to 5V and it worked better. However, I decided to put the ATmega328P directly on the breadboard, to make it closer to the finished product.

Edit: From what I know, USB turns off with the computer, so that's why I don't want to use it. My plan is to buy a 24 pin ATX Extender and cut into that instead.

Comment: I'm NOT suggesting you use USB to power your Arduino (even though you can make a USB not turn off when the PC sleeps), I'm suggesting you hack a USB cable to use +5VSB to power Arduino via it's onboard USB socket.

Answer (score 2):

The picture of your setup clearly shows that the board IS NOT powered via right connector. The red circle shows no wires, maybe to Vin only:
[image]

You should be connecting the +5VSB to "power connector" +5V pins,

[image]

More, you also seem to have an extra diode in series with power supply, which likely adds another 0.7 V of voltage drop.

Just connect the +5VSB wire directly to "5V" pin, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The computer MOBO may use a significant amount of the available current on the 5VSB output of the power supply. You should check the voltage from 5VSB to GND when you have your load hooked up using a digital multimeter (DMM). If the load is causing the voltage to sag down to less than 4.75 volts you are overloading the power supply. In that case remove your load.

BTW. You should really arrange for heat shrink tubing or electrical tape to insulate those connections you made.

Comment: I'm dropping down to 4.08 volts, so I'm overloading the power supply. I thought it wouldn't be that easy to overload it. Is there anywhere else I can draw the power from?

Comment: I'd bet you are measuring the Arduino 5V (you measure 4.08 V)) on the Arduino board and not at the +5VSB input. There is no way you are collapsing the +5VSB supply.

Comment: You were right. I checked where I had soldered, and there I get 4.93 V

Comment: @JackCreasey - You cannot say with assurance that there is no way that the OP is collapsing the P5VSB supply. How can you know that the OP hasn't connected up something on the external plug board that is sinking a couple amps of current? A good share of the computer power supplies I have worked with are rated for 3A on the 5VSB output....even an 850W unit from EVGA that I just checked. The 15W rating is also what we see on virtually all the server power supplies I work with on the job.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I'm glad you agree on the +5VSB current rating. I would say again there is no way the OP is pulling the standby power down to 4 V ....this would result in there being some components that are letting out vast quantities of magic smoke at those power levels ....and none seems to have been reported?

Comment: @JackCreasey I can confirm, I haven't seen any magic smoke, and now when I know I shouldn't drop the voltage down to 4.75 I'm going to keep an eye on it. But I don't think any of my components I'm going to use are that power hungry.